# Custom Action Salesforce1 redirect to source record

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component, publisher-action

I have a custom action set up for use in Salesforce1. I want the user to be able to click the action, create an event and be redirected to the Account record where the action was initiated. Nothing I've tried brings the user back to the Account record in SF1.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Here's my VF page:

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="Acct_Action_Extension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <script>

    function backToAcct() {
     sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!account.id}');
   }

  </script>

  <apex:form >
   <apex:sectionHeader title="Create Drop-In Meeting">
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Event">
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton value="Create Drop-In Event" action="{!dropInEvent}" onclick="backToAcct();"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:sectionHeader>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Here's my Extension:

```
public class Acct_Action_Extension {

    private Account acct;
    Id acctId;

    public Acct_Action_Extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        acctId = stdController.getRecord().id;
    }

    public void dropInEvent(){
        List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :acctId];

        List<Event> evList = new List<Event>();

        for(Account a : acctList){
            Event evt = new Event();
            evt.StartDateTime = system.Datetime.now();
            evt.DurationInMinutes = 60;
            evt.OwnerId = Userinfo.getUserId();
            evt.Subject = 'Drop In Meeting: '+a.name;
            evt.WhatId = a.id;
            evt.Type = 'Meeting';
            evList.add(evt);
            System.debug('------------evt-------'+evt);
        }

        if(evList.size() > 0){
            insert evList;
        }

        //Removed PageReference method, replaced with void
        /*PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+acct.id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, here's my code:

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="Acct_Action_Extension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

  <apex:form >
   <apex:sectionHeader title="Create Drop-In Meeting">
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Event">
      <apex:commandButton value="Create Drop-In Event" action="{!dropInEvent}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:sectionHeader>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Extension:

```
public class Acct_Action_Extension {

    private Account acct;
    Id acctId;

    public Acct_Action_Extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        acctId = stdController.getRecord().id;
    }

    public PageReference dropInEvent(){
        List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :acctId];

        List<Event> evList = new List<Event>();

        for(Account a : acctList){
            Event evt = new Event();
            evt.StartDateTime = system.Datetime.now();
            evt.DurationInMinutes = 60;
            evt.OwnerId = Userinfo.getUserId();
            evt.Subject = 'Drop In Meeting: '+a.name;
            evt.WhatId = a.id;
            evt.Type = 'Meeting';
            evList.add(evt);
            System.debug('------------evt-------'+evt);
        }

        if(evList.size() > 0){
            insert evList;
        }

        PageReference pg = new PageReference('com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId='+acct.id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
}
```